# Oracle rdb - not able to find rdbthin-7.4.3.1-jar. Can someone provide the link to download it

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle-rdb

I am using rdbthin on openvms system. Currently I am using jar in my application with version 7.3.1.0. I am asked to upgrade it to version 7.4.3.1. I am not able find it anywhere including Maven Central repository and Oracle archive. Can someone provide the link to download it? Jar name - rdbthin-7.3.4.1.jar

Comment: You need to contact Oracle support. At least the [download page](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/rdb/downloads/index.html) states: "*Please check My Oracle Support "Patches and Updates" for newer versions.*"

Comment: Trying to raise a support but it is asking for support identifier which i don't know where to find

Comment: You should ask your DBA or possibly an admin from the IT department maintaining your contracts with Oracle.

Comment: My client had subscribed for support from Oracle and they provided it. Thanks